# Vmware Server virtual machine can see all network other than its host

Tags: networking, virtualization, vmware-server

The virtual machine is sitting on 192.168.0.104 on a bridged connection
The host machine is sitting on 192.168.0.103.
I can ping the virtual machine from the host
I can't ping the host machine from the virtual server, nor can I access any of the services on it (SMTP/Fileshares/etc).

I have tried rebooting both Vmware and the virtual machine but it seems to make no difference. I have tried a repair on both of the adaptors and no difference.

Help!

EDIT: The Virtual machine has no issue seeing everything else on the network, and vica versa.

Comment: Is the firewall enabled on the host?

Comment: Could you post the ip and routing details for the guest and host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a physical issue in the end!